# What conditions are necessary for a decreasing, sequence of positive dyadic fractions with never-decreasing denominators, to converge in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, soft-question

> What conditions are necessary for a decreasing sequence of dyadic fractions with never-decreasing denominators, to converge in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Consider a sequence $x_m,x_{m+1}\ldots$ of dyadic fractions in which:

- the denominators are never decreasing (i.e. 1,2,2,4,4,4,8,...)
- the sequence is decreasing
- every element is positive
- the difference from one to the next is reducing (i.e. $\lvert x_{m+1}-x_m\rvert<\lvert x_m-x_{m-1}\rvert$)

What further conditions are necessary to guarantee convergence in $\mathbb{Q}$?

It would seem trivial that a) the differences from one term to the next must converge to zero in finite number of terms and therefore b) the denominators must converge to a fixed power of $2$.  This must also require that the numerators converge to some fixed integer in $\mathbb{N}_2^{\times}$

Is there some other way of characterising convergence in $\mathbb{Q}$ or some accepted rule or property guaranteeing convergence in $\mathbb{Q}$ which is analogous to e.g. the Cauchy rule for convergence in general?

Comment: You need quantifiers. In A you should add "For all n>1" for example. For B do you mean "For all $n, x_n\in \mathbb{Q}$, $x_n>0$". Similary for C.

Comment: @Somos It's in $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm trying to understand the minimal set of conditions required and then a proof.

Comment: $|x_{m+1}-x_{m}|=|x_{m}-x_{m+1}|$ always, what do you mean with your first condition?

Comment: @MatíasBruna I mean the difference between two terms in the sequence is less than the difference between the two preceding terms, so like $31,24,30,25,29,26,28,27$ fulfils this rule but it's less than not equals which you wrote.

Comment: The fact that one is considering convergence **in the set $\mathbb Q$** is crucial to the question and not even mentioned.

Comment: Yes and this is irrelevant to my remark. No.

Comment: @Did I was at first a bit baffled but I think you were pointing out a sequence of terms in $\mathbb{Q}$ can converge to a number not in $\mathbb{Q}$.  Is it worded better now?

Comment: Next time, to skip the "baffled" step, just read what I write.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexamples:

For A, $\sqrt{n} \to +\infty$ and $\sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2} + \sqrt{n+1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}= \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}.$

For B, take any decreasing sequence of rationals converging to an irrational.  Any such decreasing sequence bounded below has a limit, but not necessarily in $\mathbb{Q}$.

For C, sequences of dyadic rationals (of the form $a/2^k$ where $a$ is an odd integer and $k$ is a positive integer) need not converge to a rational number, since the dyadic rationals are dense in the real numbers.

A concrete example is

$$\left(\frac{3^3}{2^3},\frac{5^5}{2^{10}}, \frac{9^9}{2^{27}}, \ldots \right)$$

where $x_n = (1 + 1/2^n)^{2^n+1}$,  converging to $e$ and satisfying conditions A, B, and C.

Comment: Thanks. I actually need convergence in $\mathbb{Q}$ so for that I guess the last condition is needed. But is it sufficient?  The question asks; what conditions are needed in order to prove convergence.

Comment: Added: If you are trying to prove with condition $C$ that the sequence must converge to a rational number, then it is false since dyadic rationals $a/2^k$ are dense in the reals.